# What part of speech is "booed" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

I have a friend who says sentences like, "Santa Claus deserves booed".  I would say, "Santa Claus deserves to be booed". Are we both correct?  Leaving out the "to be" part of the sentence seems odd to me.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: It would be valid syntax (if poor logic) to say "Santa Claus was booed", or, if Santa Claus was reciprocating, "Santa Claus booed".  And "Santa Claus deserves booing" is proper syntax as well.  But not "Santa Claus deserves booed."

Comment: @HotLicks- Or even "Santa Clause deserves *to be* booed."  But I've run into this "needs washed" construction with some of my mid-western/Minnesota(?) friends.

Comment: Thank you all for your well informed responses. My friend is from the mid-west, and so am I, but I'd never heard anyone speak this way before. I really like the "Santa Claus deserves food" response! However, I'm sure he was saying Santa Claus deserves booed. Yes, he also would say, "the clothes need washed". I believe from my grammar days that "washing" is the correct word, because "washing" is a gerund? Thanks again for your responses.